# pyOpenSSL version in identity-toolkit-python-client

Tags: python, pyopenssl, google-identity-toolkit

While automating a clean system install I came across the following:

I install

```
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev libffi-dev
pip install pyopenssl
pip install service_identity
```

And then later on I do a

```
pip install identity-toolkit-python-client
```

This last command results in

```
Installing collected packages: httplib2, rsa, oauth2client, pyOpenSSL, simplejson, identity-toolkit-python-client
  Found existing installation: pyOpenSSL 0.15.1
    Uninstalling pyOpenSSL-0.15.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pyOpenSSL-0.15.1
Successfully installed httplib2-0.9.2 identity-toolkit-python-client-0.1.7 oauth2client-1.5.1 pyOpenSSL-0.14 rsa-3.2 simplejson-3.8.1
```

Doing a

```
import OpenSSL
OpenSSL.version.__version__
```

prints out `0.14`

Is there a specific reason why

```
install_requires = [
  'oauth2client>=1.3.2',
  'pyOpenSSL==0.14',
  'simplejson>=2.3.2',
]
```

it is locked to version 14 in [https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-python-client/blob/master/setup.py](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-python-client/blob/master/setup.py#L6)?

Could this become a security issue for the system?

Comment: I would suggest raising an issue on GitHub for the project. I don't think there is a reason because the latest change to that dependency was just a commit called "Update dependencies" and it gives no reason for locking at 0.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for raising the question Daniel. The fixed was submitted to [github](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-python-client) just now.

Comment: until pushed to pypi, `pip install -U https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-python-client/archive/master.zip` does the job, which also retroactively uninstalls the 0.14 version so that everything is fine.

Comment: Just updated the library on PyPi, so `pip install identity-toolkit-python-client` should be okay now.